# Store Variable value from server to client

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6

I am using this code to connect to server.
'Client-Side Connect Code

```
 sockMain.RemoteHost = 192.168.1.125
 sockMain.RemotePort = 12345
 sockMain.Connect
```

'Server Side code to send message to client

```
   sockMain.SendData txtSend.text
```

Now, if i write :: a="127" , and send it to client from server, then this message will be displayed in textbox on client side , now how can i use this message , a="127" to store variable value ?

Comment: You're wanting to use the value sent in the text as a local variable in the receiving application?

Comment: Yes. right. But is it possible. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot literally create a new named variable within a compiled VB6 application at runtime in the manner described. You can, however, certainly extract the *numeric portion* of the value in the textbox and *assign* that value to a local variable in the application.

If you want to capture the numeric portion of the value in the textbox, and you know the text format will always be of the form "a=somenumber," you can strip off the first two characters to eliminate the "a=" portion, and then use the VB `Val' function on the remaining string to capture the numeric value:

```
   ' Generalized example for pulling integer portion from
   ' a textbox of the form 'a=12345'; amend as appropriate. Untested.

   Dim a as integer
   Dim receivedData as String
   ' Assuming txtBox1 as the name of the textbox in the client
   receivedData = txtBox1.Text
   receievedData = mid$(value,3)
   a = Val(receivedData)
```

`

Comment: i dont wanna create new variable , i have to assign value to the public declared variable from server --> to --> client

Comment: You already have a variable within the client program, and you wish to assign the numeric value from the textbox to that existing variable?

Comment: I've amended the answer as best I can to match what I think you're needing @MilindOswal